# Me sale Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'good'

Tags: python

ayuda por favor ,mi problema es el siguiente: Quiero importar el módulo alpha del sub-paquete "good" pero me sale error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'good'  y no sé por qué. El archivo alpha.py contiene la siguiente información :

---

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

""" example module: extra.good.alpha """

def FunA():
    return "Alpha"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("I prefer to be a module")
```

---

*Imagen del problema :*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

el error menciona que no fue capaz de encontrar el modulo llamado "good", puede ser por las siguientes 3 opciones:

-No tienes ningún modulo llamado "good"
-La ruta de importación del archivo está mal.
-El modulo no esta configurado para importarse

Puedes ir a la declaración de tu modulo

la importación debería ser

import good

la declaración debería ser algo como:

```
""def good():
     return variableRetorno""
```

Comment: has identificado el problema pero no brindas ninguna solución. ¿Cómo solucionas el problema?